# Remote Elasticsearch connection from local rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, localhost

I have a rails app that is running on a remote elasticsearch server. Rails console works fine with the connection to Elasticsearch remote server but when I try to do anything like `db:migrate` or `assets:precompile` it looks like it tries to connect to elasticsearch local server and throw the error 
`Faraday::ConnectionFailed: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200`

Comment: Can you provide a pastebin/gist link to your ElasticSearch configuration?

Comment: Elasticsearch::Persistence.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new url: "somewhere.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:80"

Comment: Could you provide your `elasticsearch.yml` config? If you're running a linux distro its likely in your `etc` directory probably something like `/etc/elasticsearch.yml`

Comment: You know what this could be a VPC or Security Groups issue, sounds like issues I've had in the past with VPC. But go ahead and provide your elasticsearch config so we can make sure that's not an issue. If it is infact a problem with VPC or security groups you'll either want to edit this question heavily or start a new question and add the tag `AWS`, unless you can solve the problem on your own.

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want to use elastic search, then remove its config settings from initializers folder(if you have created any).

But, if you still want to use elastic search and since I do not you how your configuration setting looks like, start elastic search in another tab in terminal to avoid this.

Comment: I'm using `Elasticsearch` but not running the server locally, I'm connected to it from a remote server. I don't want to remove it from the initializers, I'm just wondering why one place is connecting to the remote servers while others are trying to connect to local (which doesn't exist)

Comment: i cannot comment so I need to write it in an answer tab.. dont know why someone down voted it